# The requested resource (/) is not available

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I have just started learning Spring MVC 3 and I have problem right at the start with running simple hello world program

I'm trying to get [this](http://blog.springsource.org/2011/01/04/green-beans-getting-started-with-spring-mvc/) up and running, but i cant for some reason

I'm constantly getting this error

```
type Status report

message /

description The requested resource (/) is not available.
```

Here is my `servlet-context.xml` file

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->
    
    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <annotation-driven />   
    
    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>
    
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.test.test" />
    
    
    
</beans:beans>
```

`web.xml` file

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    
    <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Processes application requests -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
        
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

HomeController.java

package com.test.test;

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;


@Controller
public class HomeController {
    
    @RequestMapping(value = "/")
    public String home() {      
        return "WEB-INF/views/home.jsp";
    }
    
}
```

I'm using Tomcat 7.

Anyone know what is cosign this error?

Comment: Did you check the startup log, with logging at debug level?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@Tenelope you need not return `"WEB-INF/views/home.jsp";` you can just return `"home"` as you have it configured in your servlet-context :

```xml
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>
```

My advice to you would be to download the spring source(eclipse like IDE) :

http://www.springsource.org/springsource-tool-suite-download

After downloading it you can simply go to `File > New > Spring Template Project > Spring MVC project`

After you're done with creating project, the working template project(structured project, example controller file, example view, pom.xml etc.) will be created for you. Including the `"/"` example you're talking about. You can just build it and deploy it to tomcat or whatever.

This way you already get working example and you can take it from there.

Btw. check this out :

https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-mvc-showcase/blob/master/MasteringSpringMVC3.pdf?raw=true

It is enough to get you started well off with Spring MVC.

Comment: I'm using springsource tools and template you have mentioned, I have tried 'return home' but I'm getting 404

Comment: @Tenelope did you try localhost:8080/yourwarname/ ? is your .war in the webapps directory in your tomcat server?

Comment: It just returns blank page with no HTML at all, I dont see any .war file in webapp directory

Comment: @Tenelope that's why it returns blank, you need to build the project first. Navigate to the project root via command line (where pom.xml file is located), then `mvn clean install`, after app has been successfully built go to target directory, you will find .war file there. Just copy it to the webapps directory and it should work.

Comment: Got it working, I was using /test instead of /Test, never thought that it's case sensitive, thanks for trying to help :)

Comment: @Tenelope np so it was the warname, cool I was really interested what was wrong. Anyways have a good one. Good luck with spring mvc!

Comment: @Tenelope - 1)  URLs are always (potentially) case sensitive, so anything that you map URLs to is also potentially case sensitive.  2) If you are running software on a UNIX / Linux platform, everything is case sensitive by default.