# Spring 3.1 REST with JSON: Not working

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, tomcat

Once I moved my test application to a productive (?) application and started testing on Tomcat, my Spring 3.1 based REST services have stopped working. Though the default index.jsp is displayed, my application (http://myhost:myport/test-webapp/myrestservice) cannot be accessed and I get The requested resource (/test-webapp/myrestservice) is not available.

Here is what I did:

Controller:

```
package com.test.webapp.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

import com.test.webap.entity.Account;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/myrestservice")
public class AccountController{

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, produces="application/json")
@ResponseBody
public Account getEntity() {
            // ... <simplified>
    return new Account(//...);
}
}
```

Dispatch Servlet configuration:

```
package com.test.webapp.web;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRegistration;

import org.springframework.web.WebApplicationInitializer;
import org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet;   
import com.test.webapp.config.AppConfig;

public class AppInit implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    private static final String DISPATCHER_SERVLET_NAME = "dispatcher";

    public void onStartup(ServletContext container) throws ServletException {
        // Create the dispatcher servlet's Spring application context
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext dispatcherContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        dispatcherContext.register(AppConfig.class);

        // Manage the lifecycle of the root application context
        container.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(dispatcherContext));

        // Register and map the dispatcher servlet
        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = container.addServlet(
                DISPATCHER_SERVLET_NAME, new DispatcherServlet(dispatcherContext));
        dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        dispatcher.addMapping("/");

    }
}
```

Configuration class:

```
package com.test.webapp.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan( basePackages = {"com.test.webapp.controller"})
public class AppConfig{
    // Nothing here. Once I start using the beans, I will put them here
}
```

And, web.xml has not much in it:

```xml
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
"-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
"http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
  <display-name>Test Web App</display-name>
</web-app>
```

There is nothing apart from this in my project. Am I missing something? The old project which was doing a bit more like logging the incoming JSON requests etc (which got deleted now) was working, but I do not have it anymore :( So, lots of newbie blues. Please help me here. Thanks a lot!!

**Update** 
Issue is resolved. Check the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue resolved. I felt that this is a Servlet container 3.0 issue and may be something in my Tomcat 7 config is messed up. But, I did some minor changes to `web.xml` and it works fine now:

```xml
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    metadata-complete="false">

    <display-name>Test Web App</display-name>
</web-app>
```

Apparently, I had to explicitly tell Tomcat to scan for the implementations of ServletContainerInitializer and not everything is in web.xml via the attribute **metadata-complete="false"**

Comment: Remove the DOCTYPE, it's invalid - you're telling the app it's a Servlet 2.3 AND 3.0 versioned app.

Comment: I realized it immediately after I posted the answer :-) Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 2):

What version of Tomcat are you using in your production environment?  It looks like you will need Tomcat 7 to get the Servlet 3.0 spec implementation needed to support your WebApplicationInitializer.

Comment: I am on Tomcat 7.0.17. And yes, in my previous app version, I followed Spring3.0 and the web.xml has bootstrapping configuration entries. But, as far as I understood, with Spring 3.1, I do not need to do this configuration in web.xml - it should have found WebApplicationInitializer. I just remembered how my web.xml was earlier, and switching to that makes this app work. But with Spring 3.1, isn't it supposed to work without so much of configuration in web.xml? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks Joel, I used your Servlet3.0 spec hint and found a way to get the stuff working.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried going to the Tomcat Manager and seeing what's deployed? It should show a list of deployed apps. I'm thinking the path has changed.

Comment: I did this already, and I do see /test-webapp listed there. http://myhost:myport/test-webapp/ displays the default index.jsp, but http://myhost:myport/test-webapp/myrestservice results in "The requested resource (/test-webapp/myrestservice) is not found" error on Tomcat7.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're new to Spring I'd recommend you take a look at my previous answer :

[The requested resource (/) is not available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10264291/the-requested-resource-is-not-available/10264415#10264415)

Comment: Thank you. I already bumped on your answer while searching stackoverflow for an answer to my probs. While I added Spring IDE from eclipse marketplace, I still could not solve my problem.