# Maven + Spring MVC + LessCss + Wro4j

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc, less

I need and example of how to integrate Maven, Spring MVC, LessCss and Wro4j if i'm going in the wrong direction then, is there any other software that could do the integration of spring mvc + maven and lesscss painless??

Comment: oh my god i had never heard of lesscss thank you

Comment: There are plenty of tutorials about maven & springMVC. Wro4j is framework agnostic. Integrating all these technologies should be straightforward. If you have a more specific problem, just post the question.

Comment: What a want to achieve is app "hot relaod" of resources (css and js), the problem that araised was not integrating maven/spring mvc but using lesscss instead, due to the fact that i need to manually compile .less archives and then re-deploy de app to see changes which is such a pain!..., i'm a newby on spring-mvc world but i got experience on RoR which offers all of this in a  transparent way; that's why i want to introduce lesscss and wro4j but i can't find any actual docs about at least maven and lesscss.

Comment: If you need "hot reload", you could use the filter which performs the bundling and processing on the fly. You might find these resources useful: http://code.google.com/p/wro4j/wiki/ManageResourcesWithoutRestartingServer

Comment: And m2e-wro4j eclipse plugin: https://community.jboss.org/en/tools/blog/2012/01/17/css-and-js-minification-using-eclipse-maven-and-wro4j

Comment: ant, i already have working springsource with a spring mvc + maven project, thxz anyway.

Comment: Thanks Alex Objelean!!!!, m2e-wro4j is fantastic that's what i was looking for!!!, if u want post it as an answer so i can vote on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try the [m2e-wro4j](https://community.jboss.org/en/tools/blog/2012/01/17/css-and-js-minification-using-eclipse-maven-and-wro4j) eclipse plugin.

Answer (score 0):

As explained in my previous [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10264291/the-requested-resource-is-not-available/10264415#10264415) :

My advice to you would be to download the spring source(eclipse like IDE) :

http://www.springsource.org/springsource-tool-suite-download

After downloading it you can simply go to File > New > Spring Template Project > Spring MVC project

After you're done with creating project, the working template project(structured project, example controller file, example view, pom.xml etc.) will be created for you. You can just build it and deploy it to tomcat or whatever.

This way you already get working example and you can take it from there.

Btw. check this out :

https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-mvc-showcase/blob/master/MasteringSpringMVC3.pdf?raw=true

It is enough to get you started well off with Spring MVC.

As using lesscss that should be pretty much straight forward after you have everything else working.